# Firefox opens in wrong languge, despite Language settings

Tags: firefox

I have followed the [instructions here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-firefox-another-language) to change the language and restarted the browser.

[image: Firefox language settings]

However, Firefox still shows everything in German language. Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: What if you delete `German` in the list?

Comment: Unfortunately, the remove button is greyed out when either German or English are selected.

Comment: Could you add some details? FF Version and installer language, OS and version, and default system language.